# How can I create a piechart that looks like a pie using CorePlot?

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot, pie-chart

The graph on the left is the one from the CorePlot gallery demo, the one on the right is the one I created with the code below. I think **I am missing something in order to make it look like an actual circular pie**:

[image]

```
-(void)configureChart {
    // 1 - Get reference to graph
    pieChartGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.pieChartgraphHostView.bounds];
    self.pieChartgraphHostView.hostedGraph = pieChartGraph;

    // 2 - Create chart
    pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
    pieChart.dataSource = self;
    pieChart.delegate = self;
//    pieChart.pieRadius = (self.pieChartgraphHostView.bounds.size.height * 0.7) / 2;
    pieChart.pieRadius = (self.pieChartgraphHostView.bounds.size.height * 0.7) / 2;

    pieChart.identifier = pieChartGraph.title;
    pieChart.startAngle = CPTFloat(M_PI_4);
    pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
    pieChart.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    // 3 - Create gradient

    CPTGradient *overlayGradient = [[CPTGradient alloc] init];
    overlayGradient.gradientType = CPTGradientTypeRadial;
    overlayGradient = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0] atPosition:0.9];
    overlayGradient = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4] atPosition:1.0];
    pieChart.overlayFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:overlayGradient];
    // 4 - Add chart to graph

    [pieChartGraph addPlot:pieChart];

    pieChart.dataSource = self;

    self.dataForChart = [@[@20.0, @30.0, @60.0] mutableCopy];


    //self.dataForChart = [@[@20.0, @30.0, @60.0]mutableCopy];
}
```

I tried to copy the code from the demo gallery (class called **CorePlot** from the CorePlot [example project her](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/0138add05c6807a4f5b14d7ce07a20db7af58c80/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/CompositePlot.m)e).

**What am I doing wrong? Why is my graph a square and not a circle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try edit the radius of the chart. That is what makes it a circle. To obtain a circle from a square view you usualy do something like:

```
squareView.radius = view.frame.size.width/2;
```

You can try this on you pieChart:

```
pieChart.pieRadius = pieChart.frame.size.width/2;
```

And by the way you are setting 2 times the pieChart dataSource